# using .load() with a variable and mutliple identifiers

Tags: jquery, load

Ok so this is quick start to my jQuery

```
var uid = $('#mem_week a').attr('href');
$('#usersImg').load(uid #profile-advanced-right img);
```

Not quite sure if I can write the var `uid` inside the .load() like that, plus I need to be specific on the id `#profile-advanced-right img` is this possible?? if not can someone show how I would write this?>

Generated Mark up::

```
<div id="mem_week">
 <h3>
  <a href="/u1">Mr.EasyBB</a>
 </h3>
   <div id="usersImg"></div>
 </div>
```

That is just a basic mark up. Really I am trying to grab the users Image from the url /u1 from the div `#profile-advanced-right .main-content img` as though and out come should be

```
<div id="mem_week">
 <h3>
  <a href="/u1">Mr.EasyBB</a>
 </h3>
   <div id="usersImg">
     <img src="usersimg.png"/>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: `.load(uid + " #profile-advanced-right img")`

Answer (score 3):

Close. This is what you want:

```
$('#usersImg').load(uid + " #profile-advanced-right img");
```

You could have found this out by reading the jQuery [`load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) documentation. It's generally a good idea to check the docs before asking a question here on SO. :)

Comment: I don't think that is what he's saying - my reading is that the url has an html fragment and he wants to grab the img from inside that html fragment

Comment: Unless it's the hash part of the URL, you should probably add a space ?

Comment: @adeneo - that doesn't make sense, the hash part of a url is not sent to the server

Comment: @adeneo, you have a point. @GeorgeMauer, if it's an HTML fragment then he can't use `$.load()`, right? My understanding is that he's saying he wants to load DOM HTML, and if that's the case then my answer works.

Comment: $.fn.load works ONLY with html fragments. You only use it as a shortcut to when you don't want to do anything with the returned html. See my answer.

Comment: @GeorgeMauer - My point was that without the space, it's a hash on the end of the URL, with the space the .load() function will find() that element and append only that element, so my comment was just a kind reminder that the answer was probably wrong until a space was added, and now it looks ok to me, in fact it does exactly what your answer does, in one line. It had nothing to do with the hash being sent to the server or not.

Comment: Oh - you are quite correct, I didn't know that was part of the load api. Kinda cool

Comment: Ahh okay, I may have misunderstood something then, as I was quite sure that `$.load()` worked with non-fragmented HTML.

Comment: only problem is it is loading all images :) any way to be specific on how to load the element?

Comment: oh and so by adding the space " #div" makes find the element after the variable...instead of "#div"

Answer (score 2):

So load basically does the same thing as this:

```
$.get(url).done(function(htmlFragment){ //get the html fragment at this url (it will be a string)
  $('#myElement').html(htmlFragment); //set the contents of your element to that html fragment
});
```

In other words, it's a helper method for a much more complex concept. By my reading what you want is to select an img within the returned fragment and stick it in your element

```
var url = $('#mem_week a').attr('href');
$.get(url).done(function(htmlFragment){ //get the html fragment at this url (it will be a string)
   //parse the string with jquery and navigate to that node
  var justTheImg = $(htmlFragment).find('#profile-advanced-right img');
  //set the contents of your element to that img (using the html method might also work)
  $('#myElement').append(justTheImg); 
});
```